# Mindslavering a Mindslavered player?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent [Mindslaver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMindslaver%5d)s me, and then I Mindslaver myself, does it "override" my opponent's control? I assume it works the same as if someone, for example, [Act of Treason](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAct%20of%20Treason%5d)s on a creature, and then someone else Act of Treasons it, simply gaining control again, but just making sure.

Comment: *How* do you plan to Mindslaver yourself if your opponent is controlling you?

Comment: @Glorfindel Because his opponent forced him to presumably.

Comment: I'd like some clarification on the timing here. Presumably the opponent activated his Mindslaver during his own turn. When are you activating your Mindslaver? During that same turn, while the opponent's Mindslaver's ability is on the stack? During that same turn, right after the opponent's Mindslaver's ability has resolved? During your own turn, while your opponent is controlling you? In that last case, I don't think there's any interesting interaction, since your Mindslaver will give you control of your _next_ turn, not your current turn.

Comment: The timing is irrelevant to the question, considering the specification of which came first present in "and then" i mindslaver myself, but if you insist, my opponent mindslavers me on his turn. It resolves. Then i mindslaver myself, when i next recieve priority.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it makes sense to me now :-) I guess my confusion was in what the shorthand of "to mindslaver" stands for. If it means "activate and then resolve Mindslaver's ability", then yours resolves last. If it means "activate Mindslaver's ability and pass priority", then yours resolves first.

Comment: Understandable.

Comment: To be fair, Glorfindel and myself both read it originally as activating your own Mindslaver while under your opponent's control; as opposed to doing it ahead of time before you would be controlled.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, your own control effect will override your opponent's, and you will make your own decisions.

> 716.1a Multiple player-controlling effects that affect the same player overwrite each other. The last one to be created is the one that works.
>
> 716.9. A player may gain control of themselves. That player will make their own decisions and choices as normal.